# Send a multidimensionnal stl::vector or array by gSoap

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

I have built a PHP soap function, receiving an array of array of strings, and writing it to a file.

Here is the WSDL file of the Soap server :

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The        document tree is shown below.
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="ADRESSE_WEBSERVICE"     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-    enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"     xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="BoWS"     targetNamespace="ADRESSE_WEBSERVICE">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="ADRESSE_WEBSERVICE"/>
</types>
<portType name="BoWSPort">
<operation name="writeArray">
<documentation>This method count and write an array</documentation>
<input message="tns:writeArrayIn"/>
<output message="tns:writeArrayOut"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="BoWSBinding" type="tns:BoWSPort">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="writeArray">
<soap:operation soapAction="ADRESSE_WEBSERVICE#writeArray"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="ADRESSE_WEBSERVICE"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="ADRESSE_WEBSERVICE"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="BoWSService">
<port name="BoWSPort" binding="tns:BoWSBinding">
<soap:address location="ADRESSE_WEBSERVICE"/>
</port>
</service>
<message name="writeArrayIn">
<part name="array" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
</message>
<message name="writeArrayOut">
<part name="return" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
</definitions>
```

That function works correctly when I tested it via soapUI like this :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="ADRESSE_WEBSERVICE">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:writeArray soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <SOAP-ENC:Array SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[][3]">
   <SOAP-ENC:Array id="array-1" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[4]">
    <item>26</item>
    <item>223</item>
    <item>test</item>
    <item>test3</item>
    </SOAP-ENC:Array>
   <SOAP-ENC:Array id="array-2" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[4]">
    <item>26</item>
    <item>750</item>
    <item>test</item>
    <item>test4</item>
    </SOAP-ENC:Array>
    <SOAP-ENC:Array id="array-3" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[4]">
    <item>70</item>
    <item>360</item>
    <item>tes321</item>
    <item>test23</item>
    </SOAP-ENC:Array>
</SOAP-ENC:Array>
      </wsdl:writeArray>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have to send to that function a multidimensionnal array/vector of string from a C++ program.

I have generated the gSoap headers and functions with wsdl2h.

The array parameter of that function is a structure generated in the soapStub.h file :

```
struct _Struct_3
{
public:
    char **__ptr;
    int __size;
};
```

My issue is I don't know how to use that structure as a multidimensionnal array.

The array that I have to insert is at origins a vector of strings vectors :

```
vector< vector<string> > testArray
```

That I can easily transform as an array of strings array.

Comment: Have you tried to generate the gSoap code with switches to use stl? (If I remember correctly there was an option allowing you to enable or disable stl in generated code.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this WSDL is that there is no type information for the array and its elements, just a reference to a generic "soap-enc:Array".

After running wsdl2h, change this declaration in the .h file that is produced to:

```
struct _Struct_3
{
    std::string *__ptr;
    int __size[2]; // 2D array
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Finally I extract each element of my 2D vector of strings, and fill them into the char** __ptr. I fill the __size with the vector[i] * vector[j] size and it works correctly.